# Should I correct for multiple comparison if I have a strong a priori hypothesis?

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I currently perform an fmri analysis, and I extract timeseries on 4 different conditions from 3 specified different regions based on the literature. Within each group, I do my statistical test (contrast condition 1 - (cond2+cond3+cond4), and as expected, the predicted area has an effect and the other two do not.

This generates 3 pvals : [0.02 0.4 0.44]. If I correct with fdr or bonferroni, the significance goes away. However, given that this was a planned analysis based on a priori predictions, should I actually correct? And if so, is there a more appropriate test for very few amount of comparisons?

Comment: If it was really the only prespecified hypothesis, then why do you have 3 regions?

Comment: the hypothesis is that there will be an effect in one regions, and not in the others

Comment: I think an analogous question is, "Should I skip statistical tests for group differences if I have a large sample."  I think no.

Comment: I think you are asking a wrong question then. Your question shouldn't be if you should correct, but got can you test that 2 regions don't have an effect and one does. There is a literature on testing joint compound hypotheses, si maybe you can test cond1>cond2 AND cond1>cond3, or maybe that cond1 has the highest effect or something else. Anyway i suggest you edit your question. Unfortunately I don't have an answer for you

Comment: Correction: the term i meant is conjunction and not compound hypothesis. Although i don't know if it apply to your problem